# Securing private keys with ReactNativeWeb

Tags: security, react-native-web

I'm working on an app on react native web, and want to secure my calls.
I thought about crypting body to prevent sniffing but that would mean setting my private key (to decipher response body) in the code (could be decompiled -> not secure).

I will have credit card information transiting so I need to be sure about my security system.

How do I store my secret keys (private hash key, apiKey...)
Or do you have other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a proxy server with some backend language and make all secure requests inside it. Never share private keys into client side.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing with firebase functions ;)